# Product of factorials of powers of two

Tags: number-theory

Is there any exact formula for the product of factorials of powers of 2? Namely, I want to calculate
$$
(2^k)! (2^{k-1})!(2^{k-2})! \;\cdot\; ...\;\cdot\; 2 = \prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(2^{k-j})!
$$
where $k$ is a positive integer.

Comment: Did this come up in some context? I'm curious what brings you to this question...

Comment: The OEIS knows the sequence, it is [A261125](https://oeis.org/A261125).  Doesn't appear to be aware of a simpler form.  It appears to count "The number of knockout tournament seedings that satisfy the delayed confrontation property." whatever that means.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs There is a context, this has shown up in the middle of a theoretical physics calculation, looking for a combinatorial factor.

Comment: The sequence grows so rapidly that Stirling approximation should work pretty well.